# A theorem of Bertini and regular sequence.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In Exercise 10.4 (p.243) in Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry by David Eisenbud, it writes

Let $a,b$ be a regular sequence in a domain $R$, and let $S=R[x]$ be the polynomial ring in one variable  over $R$.
Show that $ax-b$ is a prime ideal of S (See Exercise 17.2 for a sort of converse. Geometers will recognize this as a very weak version of a theorem of Bertini.)

I think a theorem of Bertini here means a theorem that a general hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$ intersect "correctly" with a given closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n$.

How can a Bertini's theorem relate with this regular sequence?